# How do you get the initial scale ratio of an UIView contained within a UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

This might be a noob question but do I determine the initial scaled ratio of a `UIView` when placed inside a `UIScrollView` `(UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit)`? I see that initially the ratio is set to 1.0 (zoomScale), but I'd like to know what it was scaled from.

Thanks very much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure what you mean exactly, but the initial ratio of the UIView will always be 1.0 because that is what you start with. If you are trying to get the scale after the ratio has changed then you can just use the UIScrollView's zoomScale property